# Disabling layout reset on focus out in d3 chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 chord diagram similar to the one here http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewRP/7468330 . The setup works great for me but I have a requirement to show the selected chords even after I focus out of the diagram  .As of now as per the default implementation the chord diagram resets when we mouse or focus out of the chord diagram.

The function which does the chord fading is below and I want this behaviour to be there post mouse out from the diagram .This is currently applied to the .group elements .

```
function mouseover(d, i) {
    chord.classed("fade", function(p) {
        return p.source.index != i &&
            p.target.index != i;
    });

    chord.classed("show", function(p) {
        return p.source.index == i ||
            p.target.index == i;
    });
}
```

Is there any way or handler by which we can control this behaviour .Please help me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover effect is not in the code its in the css so you need a change in the css.

In the style section remove the hover effect, so this:

```
  #circle:hover path.fade {
    display: none;
  }
```

will become this:

```
path.fade {
    display: none;
  }
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvMWxpeQ8yk4TfeRKDCm?p=preview)